# Functions of Random variables as integrals

Tags: integration, random-variables

Suppose I have

[image]

and we are asked to find the cdf of U=Y1-Y2

Then we must integrate f(y1,y2) over the dark shaded area for any given u.

[image]

according to the text the means by which we find the area of the triangle is:

[image]

However, focusing on the double integral, I feel like if I integrated these regions, I would get the 3D volume over this rectangular area instead of the triangle. [image]

I don't understand what about that integral restricts the region to that triangle rather than the rectangle of the same vertices.

Comment: The upper limit of the inner integral depends on the outer integral's integration variable

Comment: How about an example. Do you see how $$\sum_{n=1}^{10} \sum_{m=1}^n a_{n,m}$$ sums over a triangular region of index space rather than a rectangle?

Comment: This was the best analogy and the best answer. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The inner integral is over the range $0 \le y_2 \le y_1 - u$, and the RHS implies $y_1 - y_2 \ge u$ as desired.